# The str_replace and imagettftext problem with the GET method

Tags: php, get, str-replace, imagettftext

There is a problem with the GET method str_replace and imagettftext. When I change the words from the Latin alphabet to the Cyrillic alphabet, it comes out on its own

```
$cyr  = array('а','б','в');
$lat = array( 'a','b','v');
$textlatin = $_GET['textlatin'];
$textrus = str_replace($cyr, $lat, $textlatin);

imagettftext($img, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $fontColor, $fontFile, $textrus);
```

Comment: "It comes out on it's own", what does that mean? Could you please post a screenshot of what happens with latin characters and what happens with cyrillic characters.

Comment: I want to write text in krill on the picture. I switched the krill letters to Latin on another server. I sent the Latin letters to a file that writes text to the picture via Get. Now you need to replace the Latin letters that came through get in the krill alphabet and write them on the picture.

Comment: @JacobMulquin this